# How to launch Microsoft default Calendar & Calculator with selected date / calculation from UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, launch

I need to launch Microsoft default app Calendar(outlookcal:) with selected date ( ex. 01/01/2020) and Calculator(ms-calculator:) with expression/calculation (2*3=) from UWP. I am using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri())` for app launch from *.cs.

For Bing maps with location I was using `"bingmaps:?where=location"` as protocol uri & Bing maps is opened in the location set by me. I was looking for something like this for Calendar & Calculator app. Is there anything for Calendar & Calculator?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > How to launch Microsoft default Calendar & Calculator with selected date / calculation from UWP?

Currently, the calendar and calculator app have not disclosed how to call their Uri scheme to launch them with the specific data. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) demostrates how to launch the default app for a URI, you could check it. However, you can not launch the calendar and calculator app via the specified behavior.